# How to show more than two fields in a Openlayers popup on a views_geojson layer?

Tags: views, 8, javascript

I have finally gotten my OpenLayers working, and I'm trying to show 7 fields about my points in a popup. By default, [Views_geojson](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_geojson)only allows you to define a title and description fields for tooltips. I am assuming that this applies to the popups as well. Only being able to show two fields kind of limits the utility of the feature.  So, I'm wondering how I can show more of my fields in the popups? I'm using the Dev version of OpenLayers 7.x-3 and all the stable dependecies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if anyone else runs into this a simple rewriting of the fields in views will get you to where you want. You can add your html there to format the fields.